# How DEP and ASLR play role in security?

Tags: programming-languages, clr

Lines from CLR via C#:
A managed module is a standard
32-bit Microsoft Windows portable executable (PE32) file or a standard 64-bit Windows
portable executable (PE32+) file that requires the CLR to execute. By the way, managed
assemblies always take advantage of Data Execution Prevention (DEP) and Address Space
Layout Randomization (ASLR) in Windows; these two features improve the security of your
whole system.

Que: I want to know the Security in which context here and what DEP and ASLR does here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather well-documented here:

[DEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention)

[ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)

The long and short is DEP keeps data from being executed as code, such as buffer overflow attacks and ASLR keeps malicious code from knowing where other bits of code and data will be located at in memory, so it can't be easily attacked.